# Cypress - Assertions - cy.url.should is not a function

Tags: javascript, cypress, assertion

What I did :

I tried to do an assertion for a URL and I am getting the following error

Error: cy.url.should is not a function

My code :cy.url.should('contain','#/home')

Comment: Typo maybe? `cy.url().should('contain','#/home')`?

Answer (score 1):

You are close, you just missed the closing brackets.

```js
cy.url().should('contain','#/home')
```

Comment: this is a typo then surely?

Comment: Yes as per the error message.

Comment: Then please close the question as such?